# OnModelCreating get specific records (filter records)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm wondering is it possible to get specific columns from database on  `OnModelCreating` function?

For instance think about you have a database which is using by mobile and web applications. And all tables has `isMobileRecord` (boolean) column. And you don't want to write linq expression to not get `isMobileRecord = false` to list all objects in web application.

Normally I'm doing that in my generic repository so other people do not have to write an expressions but for `Include` methods as you know there is no way to filtering. I know the other ways but I'm wondering maybe there is a way to do it in `OnModelCreating`.

I know we can put some rules for decimals like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
     .Property(e => e.salary)
     .HasPrecision(10, 2);
```

PS: I also tried `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters` but could not be succesful it yet.
(https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters)

Comment: Take a look at interceptors. lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/29/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-filters/

Comment: I already used that too but no change.